# Survey Monkey - Get form data - API

Tags: surveymonkey

I'm trying to get the field values submitted through survey monkey forms. Since its in a seperate iframe, i cant access it from my domain (CORS). Is there any api to get the individual responses submitted through these forms?

Answer (score 0):

You mean you're using a website collector and the responses are embedded on your website, and you want to read the responses in javascript when the user submits the form? Yes that won't work.

Either way I think the best way to do it is to use the API.

You can fetch the list of survey responses (and their details) [see the docs.](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#survey-responses)

To get the list of responses for a survey you would do:

```
GET /v3/surveys/<survey_id>/responses
```

You can filter by date or other fields (if you need be).

You can fetch the full details with

```
GET /v3/surveys/<survey_id>/responses/<response_id>
```

Alternatively, you can setup a [webhook](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#webhooks) where you'll be notified every time a new response comes in, you can then make the request defined above to get the details of the response.

Hopefully those options work for you, I don't know your use case well enough to give other options.

Comment: thank you for ur response, my use case is simple, Lets say we have two forms in two different iframes. One belongs to my domain while the other belongs to survey monkey, and say both the forms have name and email fields in it. When the user submits name and email through surveymonkey form, my form should have these update field values.

Comment: I have already looked into webhooks where the response data has been made to sent to an endpoint url. The problem is, i have a unique id in my iframe and i need to send it along with the postdata that is being sent to through webhook.

Comment: You could add a custom variable (http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/What-are-custom-variables-and-how-do-I-use-them) and set it on load of the surveymonkey page to be the ID you want, you can then use that as an identifier when you later fetch the response and then you can store it on your side.